# SQL query: Growth of users per month in percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this easy query that calculates the number of user registrations per month.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month, COUNT(user_id)
FROM users
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC
```

What I would like to have is for every month the growth in percentages compare to the previous month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bda6e/9)

```
select
    month, total,
    (total::float / lag(total) over (order by month) - 1) * 100 growth
from (
    select to_char(created_at, 'yyyy-mm') as month, count(user_id) total
    from users
    group by month
) s
order by month;
  month  | total |      growth      
---------+-------+------------------
 2013-01 |     2 |                 
 2013-02 |     3 |               50
 2013-03 |     5 | 66.6666666666667
```

Comment: This is serious awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bda6e/7)

**PostgreSQL 9.1.9 Schema Setup**:

```
create table users (created_at date, user_id int);
insert into users select '20130101', 1;
insert into users select '20130102', 2;
insert into users select '20130203', 3;
insert into users select '20130204', 4;
insert into users select '20130201', 5;
insert into users select '20130302', 6;
insert into users select '20130303', 7;
insert into users select '20130302', 8;
insert into users select '20130303', 9;
insert into users select '20130303', 10;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  month,
  UserCount,
  100 - lag(UserCount) over (order by month asc)
        * 100.0 / UserCount Growth_Percentage
from
(
  SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
         COUNT(user_id) UserCount
  FROM users
  GROUP BY month
  ORDER BY month DESC
) sq
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bda6e/7/0)**:

```
|   MONTH | USERCOUNT | GROWTH_PERCENTAGE |
-------------------------------------------
| 2013-01 |         2 |            (null) |
| 2013-02 |         3 |   33.333333333333 |
| 2013-03 |         5 |                40 |
```

---

**Clodoaldo** is right, the growth percentage should be calculated using ([Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bda6e/14/0))

```
  100.0 * UserCount
        / lag(UserCount) over (order by month asc)
        - 100
        AS Growth_Percentage
```

Comment: What you are calculating is what is called _commercial margin_  or _gross profit margin_. I guess it is not what the OP asked for. 3 over 2 is a 50% growth not 33.3

Comment: You are absolutely right! Was thinking of profit margins..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accepted Clodoaldo Neto his answer because he/she was the first but this is also the right answer.